# #P Complexity Question

Tags: co.combinatorics

Can anyone give a polynomial reduction from computing the permanent of a matrix into counting the satisfying assignments for a 2SAT problem?

Comment: seems like homework.

Comment: It's not homework.  Since being able to solve #P-Complete problems in polynomial time collapses the entire Polynomial Hierarchy into P, it is surprising (at least to me) that counting the solutions to some very tractable problems in P is #P-Complete, two oft-cited examples being perfect matching in bipartite graphs and 2-CNF-SAT.  While the bipartite graph example is obvious by inspection, the other wasn't. After reading Valiant's paper, I see how the construction is done.


Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [The Complexity of Enumeration and Reliability Problems](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0208032), by Valiant. This is Problem number 7 in Valiant's list.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this (or something very close to it) is described in

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_is_sharp-P-complete

(under "Ben-Dor and Halevi's proof")

Comment: @Igor The question was to reduce Permanent to 2SAT, not to reduce other things to Permenant.

Comment: David, it seems that *proof* that Perm is #P-complete, which is what Igor mentions, goes through *reduction* to counting solutions of some formula. 

Comment: @quid: But the reduction is in the opposite direction. The proof goes by reduction of #3-SAT to the permanent. This does not help in reducing the permanent to #2-SAT.

Comment: Emil, thank you for the remark; I got confused. 

Comment: @David: Ah, so. I misunderestimated the OP.